# Xamarin iOS won't connect to Rest API from a Simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin iOS app that connects to an API (written by me).  Sometimes I suffer from a problem where the Simulators (running on Windows 10) will not connect to the API.  Whereas the same code runs fine on an iPhone connected to the MAC on my network.

It throws the following exception:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. 
---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 
"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.staging.MyApp.com/api/v1/LogOn/, 
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <61E93B00-972D-4DF1-BA39-0141116988C2>.<1>, 
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(\n    "LocalDataTask <61E93B00-972D-4DF1-BA39-0141116988C2>.<1>"\n), 
NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.staging.MyApp.com/api/v1/LogOn/, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x600001cac840 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, 
_kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}}, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}\n   
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  
at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d4] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:523 \n  
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, 
System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in 
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 \n  at MyApp.Mobile.Api.LogOnUser (MyApp.Mobile.VM.LogOnVM vm) [0x000b2] in D:\Projects\MyAppCore\MyApp.Mobile\MyApp.Mobile\Api.cs:114 }
```

Just to repeat, the VERY SAME code is running on the physical iphone (and android emulators/phone) perfectly.

Any ideas as to why are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could be a certificate issue and it's running up against a difference in the trusted certificate store on the device vs. the mac/simulator. Depending on what kind of cert you're using on your api, you may want to look into how to install it as trusted on the simulator and/or look at hooking into and debugging the actual certificate validation process as it happens.

Comment: the iOS simulator does NOT run on windows 10 - it always runs on the Mac.  It may display on Windows, but it is running on the Mac.

Comment: Will reboot the MAC (again ;)

Comment: That fixed it.  Jason, did you want to create an Answer - try rebooting the MAC and I will mark it as fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the information **Jason** provided, I decided to reboot the MAC.  And voila!  All working again.

I think it may be caused by me starting up 'ExpressVPN' on the PC.  I noticed when that is running, the Android won't connect either.  However, when I stop it, the Android is OK.  But I suspect the Apple never works again until the MAC is rebooted.  Not 100% sure that is the reason, but I hope this will help others.

OK - It was NOT the VPN. But rebooting the MAC seems to fix the issue every time.